# Pytorch says CUDA is not available

Tags: pytorch, gpu

I have a cuda-capable gpu on my laptop,  NVIDIA T500 . The operating system is Windows 11.

However, in my jupyter notebook

```
import torch
torch.cuda.is_available()
```

gives `False`.

I installed:

`conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=11.6 -c pytorch -c nvidia`

When I check `conda list`, it includes

```
    ....
    numba                     0.53.1           py38hf11a4ad_0
    ....
    pytorch-cuda              11.6                 h867d48c_0    pytorch
    pytorch-mutex             1.0                         cpu    PyTorch
        ....
```

From the anaconda prompt,   `nvcc --version` gives

```
> nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
> Copyright (c) 2005-2022 NVIDIA Corporation
> Built on Tue_Mar__8_18:36:24_Pacific_Standard_Time_2022
> Cuda compilation tools, release 11.6, V11.6.124
> Build cuda_11.6.r11.6/compiler.31057947_0
```

From the anaconda prompt:   `nvidia-smi` gives

```
Fri Nov 11 09:55:38 2022
\+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 526.67       Driver Version: 526.67       CUDA Version: 12.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA T500        WDDM  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A    0C    P0    N/A /  N/A |      0MiB /  4096MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
\+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

I don't know what to do and I am not an advanced user. Could you please help me with resolving the issue?

Update and answer:

The problem was that in `conda list`, `pytorch-mutex`  showed `cpu` instead of `cuda` (see output above). I uninstalled

`conda uninstall  pytorch-mutex`

This took a long time; it seemed to create inconsistencies that Anaconda automatically fixed. I then reinstalled pytorch as above:

`conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=11.6 -c pytorch -c nvidia`

Then it worked, and `conda list` listed `pytorch-mutex`  with `cuda` instead of `cpu`.

Comment: Your Pytorch installation and configuration problem isn’t a CUDA programming related question. That is why I have remove the CUDA tag

Comment: Your Python compiler for your jupyter notebook is not Python inside conda (Anaconda).

Comment: @JamesGrey  I don't understand your comment, I may lack sufficient background knowledge. Could you elaborate a bit more?